# Extracting all the still images from a movie

Tags: linux, video, motion-detection

I have a large number of paper sheets to scan. Instead of an autofeed or flatbed scanner, I'd like to use my photo camera. After a while, it occurred to me that instead of making a photo for each page, I could install the camera on a tripod, set it to record video and then extract the images from the video.

That way, I'd just have to handle the papers: Pick one, place it in front of the camera, wait a moment, replace it.

Is there a Linux software to get all images *without motion* out of a movie? Kind of a non-motion-detection.

Comment: Convert it to a [tiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF). That's *all* of them. Too many unfortunately.

Answer (score 12):

I like your idea. I guess I've found a way to do what you want.

#### Using `ffmpeg` to export frames at a given interval

You could install [`ffmpeg`](http://www.ffmpeg.org) and then convert the video into still frames.

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -r 1 image_%4d.png
```

---

#### Controlling frame rate

The `-r` option takes one number as a parameter, namely the frame rate. So the argument for this option would be *1 divided by the time you hold the sheets in front of the camera*.

For example:

- Picking a paper every second, use `-r 1`.
- Picking a paper every two seconds, use `-r 0.5` – because 0.5 frames per second mean 2 seconds per frame.
- ...

You would only have to synchronize this with your start time, so I'd suggest using a stopwatch.

#### Shifting the starting position

You can also "shift" the video by using `-ss <some number>`, where `<some number>` is the time in seconds from the start of the video. So using `-ss 5` would start at five seconds.

If you need to shift it more precisely, using a `hh:mm:ss.xxx` syntax, thus specifying milliseconds in `xxx`, for example like `00:00:00.500`.

#### Controlling output names and format

You can change the `image_%4d.png` to use more digits. `%4d` will output images like `0001`, `0002`, and so on. So this should be enough for most cases.

`ffmpeg` can also output to JPG, so you'd just have to change the suffix accordingly. I suggest using PNG though, for quality reasons.

#### Some tips

Try to use proper lighting. Set up a direct light source to the paper and set the camera to high contrast. You would maybe need to batch-edit the output files in order to crop them, remove color tint and sharpen them up.

You could use [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) to batch process them, or use a trial version of [Adobe Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/).

Comment: +1 for the general direction of the answer. What I'd like is a way to find duplicate/very similar frames and keep only those.

Comment: I'll have to look into that! If you keep to the time though you shouldn't get duplicates.

Comment: But it's hard to keep to the time. Sometimes, I have to leaf through pages or check the backside, etc. It would be much more comfortable, if the software could simply extract the first frame of all duplicates.

Comment: I understand :) Well, I have an idea that uses [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), but it would involve a bit of programming -- unfortunately don't have the time for it in the next days.

Answer (score 2):

I am a professional VFX artist, and the best way to do it is just take stills. 
We still do this kind of thing on set for small pieces of film that need to look like live action but can't quite be filmed directly.

Even if you have a registration mark on your pages, it's hard to pull out the ones with motion blur. Your best bet (least time-consuming during AND after you take the images) really is still probably take a photo, move the page, hit the photo button again.

Comment: This should've been a comment. It's a valuable remark, but not an answer to the question.